# Change variable to be used inside loop (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, variables, python-3.x

So I am programming a checkers game, and the problem I am having is with creating several pieces in a loop. I have the class creation part of the code, which I won't post here, and the rest, which I'm posting, but I don't know how to change the variable the loop is about to use. If you can lend me a hand and clear this out, I would be thankful.

Sorry for posting my code as image, I'm new to this website ( and programming) and couldn't format so that the website would accept my post. I really hope it's ok for you guys to help me!

Thanks for the help!

Further clarification: I need to use a different "piece" creation everytime the loop runs. That means the first loop has to create piece1, then piece2, then piece3... and so forward

EDIT: Posting whole code. I know format is wrong, can't help it. So, hope somebody can fix it.

```
class Piece:
    def __init__(self, kind, yposition, xposition):
        self.color = kind
        self.ypos = xposition
        self.xpos = yposition

    def getColor(self):
        return self.getColor

    def adjustY(self, change):
        self.ypos = self.ypos + change

    def adjustX(self, change):
        self.xpos = self.xpos + change

    def getY(self):
        return self.ypos

    def getX(self):
        return self.xpos

    def mover(self, direction):
        self.direc = direction
        if self.direc == "right" and self.color == "white":
            for n in alist:
                if n.getY == (self.getY - 1) and n.getX == (self.getX + 1):
                    pass
                    # NOT YET IMPLEMENTED

                else:
                    self.adjustY(-1)
                    self.adjustX(+1)

        elif self.direc == "left" and self.color == "white":
            for n in alist:
                if n.getY == (self.getY - 1) and n.getX == (self.getX - 1):
                    pass
                    # NOT YET IMPLEMENTED

                else:
                    self.adjustY(-1)
                    self.adjustX(-1)
        elif self.direc == "right" and self.color == "black":
            for n in alist:
                if n.getY == (self.getY + 1) and n.getX == (self.getX + 1):
                    pass
                    # NOT YET IMPLEMENTED

                else:
                    self.adjustY(+1)
                    self.adjustX(+1)

        else:
            for n in alist:
                if n.getY == (self.getY + 1) and n.getX == (self.getX - 1):
                    pass
                    # NOT YET IMPLEMENTED

                else:
                    self.adjustY(+1)
                    self.adjustX(-1)


piece1 = 0
piece2 = 0
piece3 = 0
piece4 = 0
piece5 = 0
piece6 = 0
piece7 = 0
piece8 = 0
piece9 = 0
piece10 = 0
piece11 = 0
piece12 = 0

alistb1 = [piece1,piece2,piece3,piece4,piece5,piece6,piece7,piece8,piece9,piece10,piece11,piece12]

k = 2

for i in range(0,11):
    if i >= 0 and i <5:
        j = 8
        m = 0

    elif i >= 5 and i < 9:
        j = 7
        m = 1

    else:
        j = 6
        m = 0
    alistb1[i] = Piece("white",j,(m + 1 + i * k))
    print(alistb1[i].getY())

# print(piece7.getY()) test reasons
```

PS: def mover is not ready yet.

Comment: Can you please fix your post? Indent your code by 4 spaces and it will render as a code block. Also, *do* post all of your code.

Comment: When in doubt, click the orange question mark to see the markdown editing help toolbar. Or, read [this help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: I think I have your code wholly fixed. One more thing: [don't use tabs for indentation](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces).

Comment: Thanks, hope somebody can answer me :D

Comment: @farmerjoe please roll back your edit, it's syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @user3258512 I can help if you tell me what you mean by "the variable the loop is about to use." What do you mean by "use?" Your `for` loop iterates over a range of integers, and the loop variable for this is called `i`. That is the variable that the loop is "using," but I would venture to guess that you do not mean that.

Comment: @2rs2ts I know how to use the for i in range... command. Let me explain my problem more thoroughly. For each time I run the loop, I'm expecting to run my loop and at the first time execute something like piece1 = Piece(parameters) to create a new object from the class Piece. At the second time, I want to do the same (with changes in the variables i and j, and therefore the parameters) but with piece2, that means using a second variable (piece2) and then run piece2 = Piece(parameters) to create the object. I need to use every variable from the list (alistb1) to create objects. Hope I'm clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to assign a variable for each piece. You are already using a list for your pieces. Instead of writing `piece1`, you can just write `pieces[0]`. (You do need to note that lists start with index 0.)

`range` has an exclusive right bound. This means that it is not included, your range ends with one less than that value. You want to use `range(0,12)`.

In python, you can add to lists dynamically. You do not need to allocate enough spaces to fit your pieces. You can use the `.append()` method of lists.

One way to write your code now is this:

```
pieces = []
for i in range(0, 12):      # 0-11
    if i < 5:
        pieces.append(Piece("white", 8, 1 + i*2))
    elif i < 9:
        pieces.append(Piece("white", 7, 2 + i*2))
    else:
        pieces.append(Piece("white", 6, 1 + i*2))
```

I took the liberty of simplifying your conditional statements (`i` will always be `>= 0` and if `i < 5` is false, then the inverse, `i >= 5`, is true, so you don't need to restate it in your `elif`) and getting rid of `j`, `k`, and `m` which are unnecessary variables and can be replaced with literals to save memory.

One more thing: your implementation of `getColor` will return the function object itself. I think you wanted to do:

```
def getColor():
    return self.color
```

Comment: Thanks! This has finally worked for *most* of pieces. There is only one thing tho. If I use print(pieces[0].getY()) it will return me a blank line (however work for pieces[1] and forward). Do you know why?

@2rs2ts

Comment: @user3258512 edit your original post to show the code you are using now so I can see if you've copied something wrong.

Comment: It's working now, I swear it just magically happened. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @user3258512 Some more advice as you move forward implementing `mover`: make sure you are invoking your methods (use parentheses), as you repeatedly just reference the method itself in your conditional blocks. I would also advise you to add `alist` as an argument to `mover`. You can pass `pieces` in as this argument.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `dictionary` and a for `loop`:

```
pieces = {}
# I'm assuming you want 12 pieces since your list has 12 pieces      
for i in range(1,13):  # range starts at m so, range(m,n) iterates from m up to n-1
    # I would suggest using more descriptive variable names if you can, row or column for example
    if i >= 0 and i <5:
        j = 8
        m = 0

    elif i >= 5 and i < 9:
       j = 7
       m = 1

    else:
       j = 6
       m = 0
    pieces['piece{}'.format(i)] = Piece("white",j,(m + 1 + i * k))
```

This should do what you want unless I am misunderstanding you. Also this isn't C++ you don't need those get methods you can simply `Piece.color` to get the color attribute of a piece.

Use the dictionary to access the pieces, `pieces['piece1'].whatever()`. However for brevity's sake you don't need to `pieces['piece{}.format(i)]` you can just `pieces[i]` and the piece would be accessed `pieces[1].whatever()`.

More info on dictionaries http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

What I have and it works with no errors:

```
class Piece:
    def __init__(self, kind, yposition, xposition):
        self.color = kind
        self.ypos = xposition
        self.xpos = yposition

    def getColor(self):
        return self.getColor

    def adjustY(self, change):
        self.ypos = self.ypos + change

    def adjustX(self, change):
        self.xpos = self.xpos + change

    def getY(self):
        return self.ypos

    def getX(self):
        return self.xpos

    def mover(self, direction):
        self.direc = direction
        if self.direc == "right" and self.color == "white":
            for n in alist:
                if n.getY == (self.getY - 1) and n.getX == (self.getX + 1):
                    pass
                    # NOT YET IMPLEMENTED

                else:
                    self.adjustY(-1)
                    self.adjustX(+1)

        elif self.direc == "left" and self.color == "white":
            for n in alist:
                if n.getY == (self.getY - 1) and n.getX == (self.getX - 1):
                    pass
                    # NOT YET IMPLEMENTED

                else:
                    self.adjustY(-1)
                    self.adjustX(-1)
        elif self.direc == "right" and self.color == "black":
            for n in alist:
                if n.getY == (self.getY + 1) and n.getX == (self.getX + 1):
                    pass
                    # NOT YET IMPLEMENTED

                else:
                    self.adjustY(+1)
                    self.adjustX(+1)

        else:
            for n in alist:
                if n.getY == (self.getY + 1) and n.getX == (self.getX - 1):
                    pass
                    # NOT YET IMPLEMENTED

                else:
                    self.adjustY(+1)
                    self.adjustX(-1)

k=2
pieces = {}
# I'm assuming you want 12 pieces since your list has 12 pieces      
for i in range(1,13):  # range starts at m so, range(m,n) iterates from m up to n-1
    # I would suggest using more descriptive variable names if you can, row or column for example
    if i >= 0 and i <5:
        j = 8
        m = 0

    elif i >= 5 and i < 9:
       j = 7
       m = 1

    else:
       j = 6
       m = 0
    pieces['piece{}'.format(i)] = Piece("white",j,(m + 1 + i * k))
```

Output:

```
>>> pieces['piece1'].color
'white'
>>> pieces['piece3'].color
'white'
>>> pieces['piece3'].xpos
8
>>> for key in pieces:
    print(key, pieces[key])


piece8 <__main__.Piece object at 0x000000000329A4E0>
piece9 <__main__.Piece object at 0x000000000329A550>
piece6 <__main__.Piece object at 0x000000000329A400>
piece7 <__main__.Piece object at 0x000000000329A470>
piece4 <__main__.Piece object at 0x000000000329A320>
piece5 <__main__.Piece object at 0x000000000329A390>
piece2 <__main__.Piece object at 0x0000000003287DA0>
piece3 <__main__.Piece object at 0x000000000329A2B0>
piece1 <__main__.Piece object at 0x00000000031D9CF8>
piece10 <__main__.Piece object at 0x000000000329A5C0>
piece11 <__main__.Piece object at 0x000000000329A630>
piece12 <__main__.Piece object at 0x000000000329A6A0>
>>> pieces['piece3'].mover('right')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    pieces['piece3'].mover('right')
  File "C:/Users/Hannah/Documents/thing.py", line 25, in mover
    for n in alist:
NameError: global name 'alist' is not defined
>>> pieces['piece3'].xpos
8
>>> pieces['piece3'].adjustX(1)
>>> pieces['piece3'].xpos
9
```

Keep in mind dictionaries are unordered so the order they print in is arbitrary.

The traceback on mover is expected since I don't have `alist` in my version of the code. You will need to modify `mover()` to work with the dictionary. Some helpful ways to work with dicts:

```
>>> for n in pieces.values():  # iterates over the values in a dict
        n.color


'white'
'white'
'white'
'white'
'white'
'white'
'white'
'white'
'white'
'white'
'white'
'white'

>>> for n in pieces.keys():  # iterates over the keys
        print(n)


piece8
piece9
piece6
piece7
piece4
piece5
piece2
piece3
piece1
piece10
piece11
piece12
```

Comment: Your method gave me no error, however, I can't access any piece I've created. E.g. print(piece4.getY()) won't work. How should I?

Plus: If possible, could you explain what you just did? Just so that I won't need to ask about it anymore :D

btw, thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm sure OP is doing this for a class, and they will always tell you to use getters and setters.

Comment: @2rs2ts I'm doing it for myself actually, still a high school student :/

Comment: @user3258512 Good on you!

Comment: @2rs2ts Can't tell if sarcasm or not, didn't mean to be rude either way, I'm very thankful for both of you for trying to help me.

Comment: @user3258512 no sarcasm here, mate. Taking the initiative to learn on your own is highly commendable and a good omen.

Comment: at 2rs2ts Thanks for the thumbs up and motivation, then ^^
>
>
>
@IanAuld print(pieces['piece1'].getY()) will give me KeyError: 'piece1' and no print :/

Comment: @2rs2ts still having the KeyError: 'piece0' problem when trying to do anything with the pieces, be it getY() or any other function.

Comment: I didn't start the `range` at 0 since your list started at `piece1`. If you want `piece0` just change the range to `range(12)`

Comment: @IanAuld I see how your code can access the information my class created, e.g. pieces['piece3'].xpos. However, I can't seem to execute any function from the class to the piece, that means I can't use getY() or move(). 

 def getY(self):
        return self.ypos

How should I change, for example this function, to call it with pieces['piece1'].getY() ?

Comment: @user3258512 You shouldn't have to change anything.